# How to backup a table using pgadmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I've tried a number of variations of settings from the 'Backup' menu that pops up when right clicking on a table but none of them have resulted in any of the table's data being backed up. The generated file is ~5k but this table has nearly 2M rows and is likely hundreds of megabytes in size.

I'd like to back this table up so I can restore it to a test database before performing some cleanup queries on the production system.

The 'Process details' window shows a series of commands but no errors indicated:

```
/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/SharedSupport/pg_dump --file "/Users/xxx/device_status_2m" --host "myhostname" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --verbose --format=c --blobs --table "public.status" "mydatabasename"
```

```
pg_dump: last built-in OID is 16383
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: identifying extension members
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: reading user-defined functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined types
pg_dump: reading procedural languages
pg_dump: reading user-defined aggregate functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined operators
pg_dump: reading user-defined access methods
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator classes
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator families
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search parsers
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search templates
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search dictionaries
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search configurations
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign-data wrappers
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign servers
pg_dump: reading default privileges
pg_dump: reading user-defined collations
pg_dump: reading user-defined conversions
pg_dump: reading type casts
pg_dump: reading transforms
pg_dump: reading table inheritance information
pg_dump: reading event triggers
pg_dump: finding extension tables
pg_dump: finding inheritance relationships
pg_dump: reading column info for interesting tables
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "public.status"
pg_dump: flagging inherited columns in subtables
pg_dump: reading indexes
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "public.status"
pg_dump: flagging indexes in partitioned tables
pg_dump: reading extended statistics
pg_dump: reading constraints
pg_dump: reading foreign key constraints for table "public.status"
pg_dump: reading triggers
pg_dump: reading triggers for table "public.status"
pg_dump: reading rewrite rules
pg_dump: reading policies
pg_dump: reading row security enabled for table "public.status"
pg_dump: reading policies for table "public.status"
pg_dump: reading publications
pg_dump: reading publication membership
pg_dump: reading publication membership for table "public.status"
pg_dump: reading subscriptions
pg_dump: reading large objects
pg_dump: reading dependency data
pg_dump: saving encoding = UTF8
pg_dump: saving standard_conforming_strings = on
pg_dump: saving search_path = 
pg_dump: saving database definition
pg_dump: dumping contents of table "public.status"
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that pg_dump does NOT work correctly for timescale hyper tables. Timescale recommends this approach instead: https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/backup